# Should there be a comma after 'I thought' if this phrase is followed by an italicised thought?

Tags: punctuation, commas, speech, italics, thought

For example, if writing:

I thought, *she may miss him, but tonight you can't tell*.

should there be a comma after 'I thought', or any other punctuation for that matter? I know commas are often used if the context is 'I said', followed by the speech,

e.g. I said, 'stop that car!'

but I'm not sure if it works the same when using thoughts and italics!

Thank you!

Comment: It works, all right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can separate any reporting clause from direct speech or direct thoughts with a comma. Cambridge [explains the rule](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech) with literally spoken words, but the same is true for thoughts and for methods of representing quotation like italics. Grammar Book [gives this example](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/quotation-marks/internal-dialogue-italics-or-quotes/):

> *I lied*, Charles thought, *but maybe she will forgive me*.

Even without italics, the comma separates the reporting clause (**Charles thought**) from the thoughts. Here's [an example](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/dealing-with-a-characters-internal-thoughts/) from Daily Writing Tips.

> It seemed a needless thing to do, Rachel thought.

Again, the reporting clause (**Rachel thought**) is separated from the thought. The absence of quotation marks or italics doesn't matter.

Comment: What if the italicized thought ends with a question mark or exclamation point? Should a comma come after the ending punctuation? See the second comma in this example: **_Nice going, Robert!_, I thought sarcastically.**